# Suppose that ten chips, numbered 1 through 10, are put into an urn at one minute to midnight, and chip number 1 is quickly removed.

Tags: limits, elementary-set-theory

**Question:**
*"Suppose that ten chips, numbered 1 through 10, are put into an urn at one minute to midnight, and chip number 1 is quickly removed. At one-half minute to midnight, chips numbered 11 through 20 are added to the urn, and chip number 2 is quickly removed. Then at one-fourth minute to midnight, chips numbered 21 to 30 are added to the urn, and chip number 3 is quickly removed. If that procedure for adding chips to the urn continues, how many chips will be in the urn at midnight (157)?"*

This question is from chapter 2 of the book "An Introduction to Mathematical Statistics and its applications, 6e by Larsen and Marx"
I have asked a tutor at school to help me but she didnt know how to solve it (yep). I also emailed the professor for assistance but he didnt get back to me and this hw will be due soon.

In my mind the urn size keeps growing, the chips move through the line through infinity and beyond, but according to the link below, its not that easy (it never is).

I see the patterns here. 9 other chips are added each time to the end of the list. These new chips are in order. Their values are in respect to the chip with the largest number that is in the urn (if that chip is numbered 10, then the chips added will be 11…20).

In addition to that, one number is removed, which is the chip with the smallest number on it. If this was a list of ascending consecutive numbers, it would be the first chip on the list. In terms of adding and removing I would say order matters.

They are added/removed at half time increments. First numbers are added at 1 minute.
1/2 is half of a minute, so that is when the second batch of chips are added, and one is removed.
1/4 is half of 1/2 so that’s when the 3rd batch of chips are added, and one is removed.
Then I am assuming the next increments should be 1/8 which is half of 1/4, 1/16 which is half of 1/8, and so on.

Also, when more chips are added, the last number value of the chips in a ascending list will always be a multiple of 10. And the total numbers of chips will be a multiple of 9.

Batch 1 added at 1 minute from midnight: 2-10 (9 chips)

Batch 2 added at 1/2 minute from midnight 3-20 (18...)

Batch 3 added at 1/4 minute from midnight 4-30

Batch 4 added at 1/8 minute form midnight 5-40
Etc.

Looking at the patterns, in my opinion, there is no way to know how many chips can possibly be in the urn at midnight because this list can grow and move through the number line through infinity.
That is because you can always break the previous time into two, forever, but its math, there must be a catch.

I would like to know, firstly, **am I miss understanding this whole thing?** Maybe I just didn’t interpret the question correctly,

**Also, what does 157 from the question (the number in parenthesis) represent?** Is that some type of a cap or information needed to "break" the infinity pattern in this question?
Does that represent time, or maybe the number of chips? Is that a hint or should I just disregard it?

**Am I correct in my analysis of the answer (grows to infinity)?**
Or, is there a specific “half of a time increment” I should use to get the correct number of chips at midnight (like, by using common sense)?
Let’s say, a regular ruler with increments will typically go as low a 1/16 of an inch. Should I follow this pattern instead?
Maybe I should calculate how many chips are in the urn at 1/16 of a minute. Or maybe since it says midnight, I should calculate it at second 0…or second 60?

**if that is the case, can someone given a hint on what formula to use?**

**Here is the answer to a similar question (link below).**

According to the the post the answer is 0...there will be no chips in the urn at midnight (?????). I mean, maybe I understood the answer totally wrong because the answer was too technical and I couldn't understand it. Please pretend Im a 7th grader or something:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315502/at-each-step-of-a-limiting-infinite-process-put-10-balls-in-an-urn-and-remove-o?newreg=f708a77b30154ff7a97792a7994c3958

**I would greatly appreciate your help.**

Comment: Note that $\lim f(x)$ is not the same as $f(\lim x)$.  Here, yes... we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|A_n\|$ may go to infinity but $\|\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n\|=0$ as the set at the end of the limiting process is empty.  Any specifically numbered chip you could imagine will have had some point at which it is removed thanks to the specific way in which you are adding/removing the chips.  Had they been added/removed in a different way, you could have a different result.

Comment: This is known in literature as the [Ross-Littlewood paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ross%E2%80%93Littlewood_paradox).  The link has far more information than we can hope to fit here in comments and the like.

Comment: Hi @JMoravitz thanks for your reply, I added some more information just in case. What would be a scenario in which the chips are added and removed in a way that would make the urn have a certain amount of chips at midnight, instead of no chips (due to the fact that they will all be removed at some point). Any idea on how I can formulate this answer? Like, is there a mathematical proof or something? I cant just tell the professor that "its empty, trust me" haha (believe me I want to)

Comment: You don't just say "*its empty, trust me*"  You say "*its empty because any specifically numbered chip you care to ask about is numbered something... call it $n$... and it was removed at the $n$'th step*".  Compare this to where you remove the chip labeled $n+1$ at each step instead... then clearly the chip numbered $1$ is never removed throughout the whole process.  Or, if the chip removed is always labeled $2n$, then all odd numbered chips remain at the end.

Comment: In the accepted answer to your linked stats.stackexchange question, there are three versions of which ball is removed at step $n$ (ball $n$, ball $10n$, or a randomly selected ball).  If it is ball $n$ removed at step $n$, then by midnight every ball has been removed, so none remain.   If it is ball $10n$ removed at step $n$, then by midnight those balls with numbers not ending with $0$ remain, i.e. an infinite number.

Comment: ... If it is a randomly selected ball removed at step $n$, then a harder calculation suggests that by midnight each ball will have been removed with probability $1$ and so the probability any balls remain is $0$.

Comment: As for the meaning of "157", unclear.  Possibly it is a page number that got copied in accidentally... In any event, I will reiterate that *all of this* is covered in far greater detail in the wikipedia article than is possible here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is covered by the wikipedia article on the [Ross-Littlewood paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ross%E2%80%93Littlewood_paradox) in far greater detail than is possible to do here.

Comment: A variation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2487556/infinite-set-probability-from-a-math-tweet

Comment: @JMoravitz believe me if there is one thing I know, is that I cant get away with the "its empty, trust me" narrative. Im not a math person clearly, proofs were never my thing, but your comment definitely stirred me in the right direction to come up with a proof for this. I will research the Ross-Littlewood paradox. Would you say that the paradox is just something I should keep in mind (like another rule) or its something that logically makes sense and one is able to get to that conclusion without knowing anything about the paradox?

Comment: @Henry see you explained it very nicely, I was very confused by the three possible outcomes. Thank you for that.

Comment: I would say that $f(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} X_n)$ is not necessarily equal to $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(X_n)$ is a rule you should learn and know to be wary of.  Learning when you *can* interchange limits is the point of several highly important theorems in analysis.  I would say that discussion on this paradox shows that it depends on interpretation and phrasing, and that appropriately phrased statements can be made to have unambiguous provable results (*even if they seem contrary to our understanding*)... there is nothing in the paradox that can be thought of as "a rule" to learn however.

Comment: ok, I will review limits and how to interchange them before I dive deep into the paradox material you guys gave me. I truly appreciate you all. I saw you want to close the question, will I lose this thread if you do so? Its my first time posting under the math stack exchange. Let me know, I will screenshot it if anything. Other than that, its fine by me. @JMoravitz

Comment: A couple of comments. First, `probability` seems an odd tag for this. It may come from a statistics text, but this question doesn't seem to have anything to do with probability, unless I'm missing something. Am I? Secondly, to me, the Ross-Littlewood paradox is analogous to the ability to rearrange merely conditionally convergent series into whatever sum one desires.

Comment: @BrianTung you are thinking of the [Riemann Rearrangement Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).  I do not feel they are directly related.  @ OP, although closing would mean no answers may be posted, it doesn't automatically mean the post will be deleted.  Also, you can always view posts made by you even if deleted.

Comment: @JMoravitz: No, I don't think they are directly related either, but something about them feels analogous (or at least reminiscent).

Comment: @JMoravitz The question is rather good. Unless it's a duplicate, I see no reason to close it. And certainly "it's addressed on Wikipedia" is **not** a good reason.

Comment: @JMoravitz Moreover, while I understand you argument about the set being empty, I don't think it's enough: one also has to justify the limit exists.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Here I have professors telling me to never rely on Wikipedia yet my question has to be closed because of Wikipedia hahahaha. So far it wasn't closed though, clearly, but it was marked as off-topic for some reason. Isn't this a mathematical question?

Answer (score 4):

It’s been suggested that this post be closed because it can’t compete with the Wikipedia article on the [Ross–Littlewood paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ross%E2%80%93Littlewood_paradox), but that doesn’t seem to be about to happen, and I think there are some aspects specific to this question that can profitably be answered here.

“$(157)$” is an unconventional way of citing the reference numbered $157$ in the reference list. In [the fifth edition](https://math.emory.edu/%7Elchen41/teaching/2020_Spring/Larsen-5E.pdf#page=760), it’s “$(148)$”, which is “Ross, Sheldon. *A First Course in Probability*, $7$th ed. Upper Saddle River, N.J.: Pearson Prentice Hall, $2006$, pp. $51$–$53$”. This refers to the Example $6$a linked to in the accepted answer to the question on stats.SE you linked to. In the [eighth edition](http://www.seyedkalali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/A-First-Course-in-Probability-8th-ed.-Sheldon-Ross.pdf#page=61) of that book, this material is on pp. $46$-$48$. It explains why there are zero or infinitely many chips at midnight in the two cases with deterministic removal and then shows that with uniformly random removal zero chips will be left with probability $1$.

The book by Larsen and Marx itself has [answers to selected odd-numbered questions](https://math.emory.edu/%7Elchen41/teaching/2020_Spring/Larsen-5E.pdf#page=734), including this one. The answer to this one uses unconventional notation that I wouldn’t advise you to adopt, but depending on the circumstances of your course it might give you some indication of what kind of answer is expected:

> $2$.$2$.$15$. Let $A_k$ be the set of chips placed in the urn at $1/2^k$
> minute until midnight. For example, $A_1=\{11,12,\ldots,20\}$. Then the set of chips in the urn is $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty(A_k-\{k\})=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k-\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty\{k\}=\emptyset$, since $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ is a subset of $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty\{k\}$.

This would be wrong under a conventional interpretation of this notation: $A_k$ doesn’t contain $k$, so $A_k-\{k\}$ (more usually written $A_k\setminus\{k\}$) is simply $A_k$, and $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ isn’t empty. They seem to be using $-\{k\}$ as a sort of signed set that can be cancelled against terms that appeared earlier in the union, so e.g. $(A_1-\{1\})\cup(A_2-\{2\})$ would be $(A_1\cup A_2)-\{1,2\}$. But then they should have started with $A_0=\{1,\ldots,10\}$, because as written they have $-\{1\}$ through $-\{10\}$ without anything to cancel them.

But the more conceptual problem here is that they simply distribute the infinite union over the set difference (i.e. swap the order of the operations of forming an infinite union and forming a set difference), and it’s not immediately clear why this should be allowed – the entire conceptual point of the exercise is being concealed in a notational sleight of hand.

Here’s how I would answer the question:

The question appears on the face of it to describe a physical process and to ask about a physical result. However, the process described is in fact physically impossible: Urns cannot hold unlimited numbers of chips, and chips cannot be added to or taken from urns at unlimited speeds. The first problem might be resolved by considering an expanding urn, but resolving the second problem would require the steps to take some constant time. We would then have to ask not how many chips remain at midnight but how many remain at the end of time, and the answer would be that this question is ill-defined.

So although the question purports to be about a physical process and thus invites us to apply our physical intuition, it actually isn’t and we actually shouldn’t. Rather, we should insist that the question define in a mathematically precise manner what it means by its terms.

The intended interpretation is that the question asks for the size of the set of chips for which there exists no step in the described process at which they get taken out of the urn. (Mathematically speaking, this is the [limiting set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior#Special_case:_discrete_metric) of the sets of chips present as we approach midnight.) It’s pretty clear that there is no such chip, so this set is empty and its size is zero.

Note that the formulation of the question is deliberately misleading. It could have just asked **which** chips are left at midnight, i.e. asked for the set of those chips rather than the size of that set. That’s less confusing because there’s no plausible alternative to the correct answer: Any set containing any chips is clearly a wrong answer because those chips are eventually removed from the urn. What makes the question of **how many** chips are left confusing is that it allows for the plausible alternative answer “infinitely many”, since that’s the answer to the seemingly similar question what the limit of the number of chips in the urn is as we approach midnight.

Comment: Hello @joriki I agree, the question is misleading. I've noticed a pattern between authors. They will usually include a handful of misleading questions to make us think harder. I read the answer sheet you linked, and your explanation of it. Thanks for "translating" all that. I am not sure why this answer was closed as not being about math. To me it clear is a mathematical problem. Also THANK YOU for explaining what 157 means. In terms of the notation of the answer, you said its not conventional. What notation would be conventional? Thanks.

Comment: @PennyBas: Conventionally, $–$ for sets means the same thing as $\setminus$, namely, $A-B$, or $A\setminus B$, contains all elements of $A$ that aren't in $B$. There are rare instances where signed sets are used, and one might also use $–$ for that, but then one would usually explicitly introduce that notation, knowing that it's usually used in the sense described above.